# Keeping all faces flat while distorting them?

Tags: transforms, faces

I'm trying to make a tank turret comprised of lots of angular quadrilateral/pentagonal faces joining together, but some of the quads keep getting "Bent" (vertices not aligning on a coplanar plane).

Is there some kind of way to freely edit vertices and edges that forcefully keeps ALL the quads on my object flat? Ideally I'd like to just extrude, resize and rearrange edges and faces, and have blender limit the range of possible angles and changes to those that retain flat faces (similar to how Sketchup works).

Comment: It is difficult to keep _all_ quads flat when transforming vertices, as even if you get one flat, some other may be distorted. However, you can use **Shift + V** to slide vertices neatly along edges, and edges neatly along eachother, although distortion may still occur.

Comment: Oh really? That's extremely helpful in itself! Would you recommend using it to try to fix existing geometry, or to start new geometry?

Comment: I couldn't really say without seeing your model, however it is often very helpful to restart a model using better modelling techniques and geometry if you aren't very far into it. I would especially recommend this if you know your new model would be significantly better/easier to work with.